# How do you broaden values in a column by only taking the first part of a value in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column in a table that has values formatted as "Company name - city". I want to be able to broaden the values and just return the company name, disregarding the city (or even creating a new column for the city).

The column looks like this when you select it

```
Company
-------
VCA - Chicago
VCA - Atlanta
VCA - Houston
```

I just want it to return this

```
Company
-------
VCA
VCA
VCA
```

I could do a case statement and go through all the companies but it would take too long.

Comment: Hint: `LEFT()` and `CHARINDEX()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use string operations:

```
select left(company, charindex(' -', company + ' -') - 1)
```

Comment: The Q tagged SQL Server `||`

Comment: @Sami . . . Sometimes, my fingers don't seem to obey my frontal cortex.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT()` and `CHARINDEX()` functions as

```
SELECT LEFT(Company, CHARINDEX(' -', Company) -1)
FROM (
VALUES
('VCA - Chicago'),
('VCA - Atlanta'),
('VCA - Houston')
) T(Company);
```